# XmlParseException occuring in PresentationFramework for deploys only

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I am getting the following exception when I deploy my WPF app to another user's machine:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

However, the WPF app runs fine when I open it.  The app crashes at StartUp with this message.  I've double-checked to make sure .NET 3.5 SP1 is installed on their machine, and also verified they can run a prototype WPF app.  Is there a good way to troubleshoot this type of error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup some code to catch unhandled exceptions:

In App.Xaml

```
<Application 
    ...
    DispatcherUnhandledException="App_DispatcherUnhandledException" />
```

In App.Xaml.cs

```
void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Add code to output the exception details to a message box/event log/log file,   etc.
    // Be sure to include details about any inner exceptions

    // Prevent default unhandled exception processing
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

If that doesn't uncover the exact issue, it may, at least, give you enough information to get started.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was causing me some serious issues, but it turned out that I really had a tcpclient that was not able to connect.